# Access to text box in other control

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

I want to deactivate a button in the event of an incorrect validation.
The text box that I would like to query for this is located in a Contentrol which is loaded into the view.
How can I address the text box by name in the control for the binding?

**MainWindow:**

```
    <GroupBox Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignCardGroupBox}"
          Margin="2">
    <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Height="32" Width="32" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                             Kind="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={x:Static infra:Constants.Camera}}"/>
                    <TextBlock  Text="Kamera Einstellungen"
                            Margin="10 0 0 0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubtitle1TextBlock}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconForegroundButton}"
                        IsCancel="True"
                        Click="WindowClose"
                        ToolTip="Fenster schließen"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Height="35" Width="35" Kind="WindowClose"/>
                    <Button.IsEnabled>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource InverseAndBooleansToBooleanConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                            <Binding ElementName="TbExposure" Path="(Validation.HasError)"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="TbGain" Path="(Validation.HasError)"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Button.IsEnabled>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>

    <Grid>
        <views:CameraConfigView DataContext="{Binding TargetCameraSettings}"  Margin="10 50 10 0"/>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

**CameraConfigView Control**

```
<ContentControl x:Class="Askion.Cryo.ColdEye.Views.CameraConfigView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:vali="clr-namespace:Askion.Cryo.ColdEye.ValidationRules"
            xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"    
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="600" x:Name="CameraConfig" x:FieldModifier="public">

<Grid Margin="0 20 0 0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <StackPanel Margin="0 0 40 0">
        <Label Content="Belichtung" Foreground="{DynamicResource LabelBrush}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="TbExposure" x:FieldModifier="public" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Belichtung" FontSize="16" Margin="2 0 0 0">
            <Binding Path="Exposure" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <vali:HaveToBeDoubleValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="40 0 0 0" >
        <Label Content="Steigerung" Foreground="{DynamicResource LabelBrush}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbGain" x:FieldModifier="public" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Steigerung" FontSize="16" Margin="2 0 0 0">
            <Binding Path="Gain" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <vali:HaveToBeDoubleValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The window cannot bind to a control in the child view by name. Use a common view model write some code to find the element in the visual tree.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't need a ViewModel. But thanks.

Comment: You don't. But you need to write some code.